# Angular HTML template error when referencing REST JSON result variable

Tags: angular, rest

I'm toying for the first time with Angular 6 and modifying some tutorial code to a slightly different purpose. I have a basic REST web service that returns JSON for only one record, whereas in the tutorial they return an array within the JSON.  I've actually got it working fine from a user perspective but I'm getting an error in the console even though functionally it's fine.

The error I'm getting is:

```
AccountDetailComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (AccountDetailComponent.html:4)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:11087)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10463)
at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10641)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10464)
at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:10662)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10459)
at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
```

Here's my component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-detail',
  templateUrl: './account-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-detail.component.css']
})
export class AccountDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  private accountDetail: object;
  private accountId: number;  // added this for testing
  constructor(private apiService: APIService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAccountDetail();
  }
  public getAccountDetail() {
    console.log('in getAccountDetail');
    this.apiService.getAccountDetail().subscribe(data => {
      this.accountDetail = data;
      this.accountId = data.id; // added this for testing
      console.log(data.id);
      console.log(this.accountDetail.id);
      console.log('done');
    },
      err => {
        console.log('Error Occurred');
      }
      );
  }

}
```

And the component.html:

```
<h1>
  Account Details
</h1>
<div>
  {{ accountId }}
  {{ accountDetail.id }}
</div>
```

The output is simply:

```
511 511
```

Which changes each time the page is refreshed as expected.

If I remove {{ accountDetail.id }} from the equation, everything is fine and there are no errors.  If I leave that in, the application still prints out the ID twice correctly on the page but shows the error in the log.  I suspect it has something to do with accountDetail being declared as an object so it doesn't know it has these specific properties like id, etc but it still manages to print the proper value..?  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: try ‍‍```{{ accountDetail?.id }}```.

Comment: Well, figured out I just needed to add *ngIf in my html code and now all is well.  Lol.  For anyone interested, here's the simple change:
    <section *ngIf="accountDetail">
    {{ accountDetail.id }}
    </section>

Comment: @fatemefazli, yeah that works too.  Is that a shortcut for *ngIf?

Comment: Your accountDetail object doesn't have the value until the API response arrives. by using ‍‍```?``` to apply the null check until the response arrives.

Comment: @fatemafazli, is there any difference between using ? and *ngIf?  Is one better than the other?

Comment: ```*ngIf``` checks if the data is not null and the ```?``` check the data null check until it arrives, they do same in this situation, i think the mark ```?``` is shorter and better.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't accept your comment as an answer though.  I'll accept the other answer here soon unless you want to post your own as the answer since you were first to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your accountDetail object doesn't have the value until the API response arrives. by using ‍‍? to apply the null check until the response arrives:

```
{{ accountDetail?.id }}
```

or as you said you can use *ngIf:

```
<div *ngIf="accountDetail">
  {{ accountDetail.id }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the following:

- When your component is constructed, accountDetail has no value, **it's undefined**.
- When you fetch some data, it becomes ASYNC. It means, the data can come after the ngOnInit. So When it will be instanciated, your html, will not find accountDetail.

What can you do ?:

```
<h1>
  Account Details
</h1>
<div>
  {{ accountId }}
</div>
<div *ngIf="accountDetail">
  {{ accountDetail.id }}
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
  {{ accountId }}
</div>
<div>
  {{ accountDetail?accountDetail.id:'' }}
</div>
```